# how to override canvas.add() method in fabric js

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, fabricjs, addition

I am working in one image editor in which I want to add image into canvas with animation. 
I try to override canvas.add() method but unable to play animation.

I am using fabric js version 1.7.22.
When i try to googling. I found one solution for add object with animation, but in that demo, they are make custom new method "fxadd()" for adding object.

Here is the reference link : 
https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/77

But My code is too long and don't want to replace funciton name at all place.
Is there any way to override existing fabric canvas.add() method then Please help me.

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.add = (function(object, callback) {
  return function() {
    console.log('add into canvas', this);
    this.add(object); // here call self method which result in infinit loop
    object.animate('top', '100', {
      onChange: this.renderAll.bind(this),
      duration: 1000,
      easing: fabric.util.ease.easeOutElastic,
      onComplete: function() {}
    });
  };
})(fabric.Canvas.prototype.add);

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1')
var btn = document.getElementById('animate');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  canvas.clear();
  setTimeout(function() {
    run();
  }, 800);
});
var run = function() {
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 10,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  });

  canvas.add(rect)
}
```

Comment: _I try to override canvas.add()_ - can you show what exactly you've tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Here is fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Mark_1998/h24u0ncm/
Please read comment in fiddle. I have write reason why this issue is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to override the prototype method using a closure, which is generally a smart way to do it, only it's not done exactly right in your snippet. Consider a simplified version of the construct you've used:

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.add = (function A(argA) {
  return function B(argsB){
    //..
  }
})(fabric.Canvas.prototype.add)
```

Here you're invoking `function A`, passing `fabric.Canvas.prototype.add` as an argument. This creates a closure, preserving the original `fabric.Canvas.prototype.add` in `function A`'s scope. Then, you're assigning whatever `function A` returns to the `fabric.Canvas.prototype.add`. In effect, this translates to

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.add = function B(argsB){ /*... */}
```

only now `function B` has access to the original `fabric.Canvas.prototype.add`.

Returning to your snippet, notice how you're expecting `object, callback` as arguments of `function A` and no arguments in `function B` - this does nothing useful (see above). Moreover, when you're calling `this.add()` - this is the place where you're supposed to call the *original* `add()` not the *new one*. Otherwise, you're getting an infinite recursion.

---

Having said that, here's the right way to do this:

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.add = (function(originalFn) {
  return function(...args) {
    originalFn.call(this, ...args)
    args[0].animate('top', '100', {
        onChange: this.renderAll.bind(this),
        duration: 1000,
        easing: fabric.util.ease.easeOutElastic,
        onComplete: function () {
        }
    });
    return this
  };
})(fabric.Canvas.prototype.add);
```

Note the usage of rest parameters `...args`, since `add()` is supposed to handle multiple objects as the arguments. I'm calling `animate()` on the first passed object, so you might want to change that.

Also, don't forget that the original `add()` is supposed to return the instance of `fabric.Canvas` for the chaining to work, hence `return this` at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much  for Help. It is  working for me